# How to set dynamic headers for Soap CXF request with reactor

Tags: spring-boot, soap, spring-webflux, cxf, project-reactor

I like to set some dynamic headers for my SOAP CXF request. I am using Spring Webflux.

I tried this:

```
var proxy = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
var headers = ...
proxy.getRequestContext().put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
port.doMyOperation(request);
```

This works fine, however the big catch is that it is not thread-safe.
I noticed that CXF has a way to make the RequestContext thread-safe:

```
((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put("thread.local.request.context", "true");
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=68110#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?

I guess this works fine with the traditional MVC approach (1 Thread per Request) and not with Spring Webflux, i.e. reactor, where threads are shared between requests.

How do I set my dynamic headers properly in a thread-safe manner with reactive progamming?